# Max Number of LinearLayouts in a ScrollView

Tags: java, android

Does anyone know if there is a max number of LinearLayouts that I can place in a ScrollView? I've done up to 25 LinearLayouts in a ScrollView, it would be awesome if I could go up to around 75 or so. Anyone know if there is a limit based on the size of the layout or based on the quantity of the layouts? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your layout is same than it would better to use [recyclerview](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html).

Comment: According to me, There is no limit for it. But if layout hierarchy increase then rendering issue you should face in lower configuration device.

Comment: Thanks for the input :) .... much appreciated.